# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Como e aonde se vota? Credo.

Comment: @Lambie é do lado direito onde diz "Your ballot".

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, já encontrei. Que coisa estranha.Você cliquea no nome e depois o voto fica na página.

Answer (score 4):

Let's make this work. Nominate yourself!

I've done my share by [nominating myself](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#post-8773), even though I believe there are enough users who are equally or better qualified than I am for the role. Don't be shy, consider doing the same and let the community make its choice — let democracy do its job and make yourself available.

It would be great to see PSE grow and I believe that having enough candidates and voters to have a successful moderator election is part of it. Contribute!

Comment: Nice to see you here! I recognize your name from [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) where you gave some good answers!

Comment: Tell me WHERE and HOW to vote. This site (SE) drives me crazy with its lack of helpfulness for USERS.

Comment: @Lambie :-) Your ballot is on the top right corner of the page https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election in a box that looks more or less like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab06H.png) after you've selected your candidate(s).

Comment: @stafusaThanks.